# Having issue on how to get AM/PM react native code?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently using this format to obtain time from the API data ( [image])

```
const d = new Date(eventData.ends_on);
const endTime = `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()${d.getSeconds()}`
```

if i would like to add AM/PM like this [image], How would the format look like in the above code. Pls do help me out.

Below is my code, I would like to implement it in this code:

```
return (
        <ScrollView style={[GlobalStyle.CustomScrollView]}>
            <HeaderBar3/>
            <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventTitle]}> Event Details</Text>
            <View style={[GlobalStyle.EventDetailView]}>
                <Image style={[GlobalStyle.EventDetailImage]} source={{uri: eventData.main_image}} resizeMode="contain"/>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventSubtitle]}>Date:</Text>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventDate]}>{date}</Text>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventTime]}>{endTime}</Text>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
```

Comment: Try :
```d.toLocaleTimeString()```

Comment: I still didn't get the AM/PM. It showing me this output "09:00:00" when i use the above tag

Comment: can you share the output?

Comment: done updating the output in question

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `toLocaleString` method, so you can provide the options you need. To use the default locale just pass an empty array to the function.

### Example

```js
const d = new Date()
const endTime = d.toLocaleString([], {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
})

console.log(endTime)
```

To use it with a predefined date, just change the first line:

```
const d = new Date(item.ends_on)
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: If I would like to use the data from api named ends_on, how should I integrate it in this code

Comment: Just add it to the `Date(...)` as normally, I've updated the answer.

Comment: i would like to implement it in my code. i have attach it in my question. how to add it without the console.log tag

Comment: The same as you have added before, probably `setEndTime(endTime)` if you are using hooks, I renamed the variable, you don't need the console.log().

Please add only one problem per question, you should make another question about your implementing problem. Check the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guides.